# cookie session is not working on CodeSandbox and Repl?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I love coding on CodeSandbox for client and Repl for server.

I am learning create an auth microservices to handle twitter login recently.

I followed this tutorial
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0/
and setup the client on CodeSandbox and Server on Repl

https://codesandbox.io/s/passport-pratice-twitter-p1ql3?file=/src/index.js

```
  _handleSignInClick = () => {
    // Authenticate using via passport api in the backend
    // Open Twitter login page
    // Upon successful login, a cookie session will be stored in the client
    //let url = "https://Passport-pratice-twitter.chikarau.repl.co/auth/twitter";
    let url = "http://localhost:4000/auth/twitter";
    window.open(url, "_self");
  };
```

https://repl.it/@chiKaRau/Passport-pratice-twitter#index.js

```
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: [keys.COOKIE_KEY],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100
  })
);

// parse cookies
app.use(cookieParser());

// initalize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
// deserialize cookie from the browser
app.use(passport.session());

// set up cors to allow us to accept requests from our client
app.use(
  cors({
    //origin: "https://p1ql3.csb.app", // allow to server to accept request from different origin
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true // allow session cookie from browser to pass through
  })
);
```

If I test them on localhost, they works perfectly (It displays login successfully)

However, testing them on CodeSandBox and Repl won't work because of req.user is undefined. The passport.session supposes to store the user session/cookie into req as req.user, and it will check whether the req.user exist and send a response back to client.

```
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: "user has successfully authenticated",
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies
    });
  }
});
```

I also tested on both localhost and browser and set the appropriate domain

Client (PC) and Server (PC) - Working

Client (PC) and Server (REPL) - not Working

Client (CodeSandBox) and Server (PC) - not Working

Client (CodeSandBox) and Server (REPL) - not Working

My Question are why the cookie session is not working on online IDE such as CodeSandBox or Repl?
Is there any solution to get around this and run on CodeSandBox or Repl? If deploy both client and server on a server like heroku or digital ocean, would it gonna works as localhost?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a frontend that set the cookie in the browser?

Comment: no, because the cookie should be created in the backend (server-side cookie)

Comment: Yes. It should be created at the server-side. But it should be store at the client-side as well. Otherwise, how does the server know if a client is authenticated or not? The common practice is to store an id of some sort on the client-side and use it to look up the session data on the server-side when the client makes a request. There should be some sort of session storage on the server-side. Your configuration now is storing the cookie in the memory. If you reload your app on the server, all those data would be gone. Express will warn you this when you run node in production mode.

Comment: Use Redis, MongoDB, sql-based DB to act as independent session storage.

Comment: Yes, kinda do the same thing on local login except it stores the JWT. What about CodeSandbox and Repl? Why they are not working while localhost does work?

Comment: Try to login on to your app on codesandbox and check the dev console in the browser for the network tab and see what it says

Comment: it doesn't log anything on either codesandbox or Repl. For the codesandbox, I think it got redirected from twitter, that's why it doesn't log anything? And I am not sure why repl doesn't log anything.

Comment: What happens when you go here "https://passport-pratice-twitter--chikarau.repl.co/auth/twitter" which is supposed to call the Twitter oauth.

Comment: the webpage will go to twitter authorize page, then redirect to homepage; it doesn't seem to be fail because the server set if fail, it will send a response to client say fail of authorize. And as I said, both client and server don't log anything (no fail). What I can think of is the cookie/session don't work on CodeSandBox or Repl. I think I will go create a project to test out the cookie/session individually on CodeSandBox and Repl. Anyways, thanks for the helps